# unable to overwrite the text file

Tags: ios, swift, file

I'm trying to overwrite the existing file everytime the application is started. I have tried two things both are not working.

1) I'm trying to create the file getting downloaded from online server with the same name but the data in the file is not getting updated, my code is..

```
 let documentsUrl:URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
            let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("Splash.text")

            let fileURL = URL(string:(defaults.object(forKey: "MainAddress") as! String).appending(filedownloadLink)
            print("proper url = \(String(describing: fileURL))")


            let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session1 = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

            print("splash file url \(destinationFileUrl)")
            let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)


            let task1 = session1.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
                if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                    // Success
                    if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                        print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                    }
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                        let fileManager = FileManager.default

                        // Check if file exists


                    } catch (let writeError) {
                        print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                    }

                } else {
                    print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
                }
            }
            task1.resume()
```

2) then i tried checking for the file before creating it, and if it exists then i'm deleting it. but once the file is deleted it is not getting opened with an error saying file "splash.text" doesnot exist. below is the code

```
 do{
                let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("Splash.text").path
                let fileManager1 = FileManager.default
                if fileManager1.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                    print("FILE AVAILABLE")
                     try fileManager1.removeItem(atPath: filePath)


                } else {
                    print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")

                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("An error took place: \(error)")
            }
```

and after this code I'm calling the code of method 1. I'm not sure why it is not getting created again for 2nd method, or why it is not overwritting it in 1st.

Comment: if the file name is not going to change, can you try creating a empty file with the same name, once the file from server gets downloaded, it will automatically be replaced.

Comment: @サンディープ i tried this but it is returing an empty file, not overwritting the file with content of the dowloaded file.

Comment: @サンディープ can you help me with a code? i'm still stuck !

Comment: ok, before deleting the file can check the file contents if it is new one or not by Checking the Devices folder in your simulator.